# Plugin hook not working on specific Wordpress installation - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to write a simple text replacement plugin, but I'm having an issue that I can't figure out how to troubleshoot.

This is the test plugin I'm using as a starting point. It works fine on one Wordpress installation running locally (installation A), but on another local installation (installation B), it has no effect on the post content. It's strange because installation b is working fine and I don't see any other bugs/issues.

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: Thanks for Reading
 */
add_filter( 'the_content', 'tfr_the_content' );

function tfr_the_content( $content ) {
  return $content . '<p>Thanks for Reading!</p>';
}
```

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: The only reason I can think of now is that you are using `the_excerpt` on your installation B

Comment: Interesting. I was using get_the_content() in both installations, but when I tried changing it to get_the_excerpt() on installation b, it's working!

How can I get it to work on get_the_content()?

PS - thanks for the help so far!!

Comment: Are both installations exactly the same, running the same theme, version and plugins

Comment: Unfortunately they're both very different. I was only using installation A to verify that the plugin code wasn't the problem. So I guess my main question now is why does the plugin work on get_the_excerpt() but not get_the_content()?

Comment: Found the answer. Apparently plugins don't work on get_the_content(), so I used the output buffering example below. I found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970625/wordpress-how-to-hook-into-get-the-content

    ob_start();
    the_content();
    $newContent = ob_get_clean();

Comment: Please post that as an answer. And mention the link as form of credit

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Apparently plugins don't work on `get_the_content()`, so I used the output buffering example below. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970625/wordpress-how-to-hook-into-get-the-content)

```
ob_start();
the_content();
$newContent = ob_get_clean();
```